# Vector potential of a Fermion

Tags: electromagnetism, fermions

Has anyone seen a 3D arrow field plot of the vector potential of a charged Fermion such as an electron? Clearly you would have the contributions of the charge and of the spin magnetic moment. I imagine it would look like some kind of spiral structure. Thanks.

Comment: There's no unambiguous notion of this because the vector potential is gauge dependent. It might help if you clarify what exactly you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The vector potential can't be that complicated. There are 2 vectors making up the problem:

1: The position vector $\bf r$

2: The spin axial vector ${\bf S} = \frac{\hbar} 2{\bf \sigma}$

From those, you need to construct a vector:

$$ {\bf A} = a(r){\bf r} + b(r){\bf S} + c(r)({\bf r \times} {\bf S}) $$

where the coefficients can be functions of position through $r= ||{\bf r}||$.

The vector potential is odd under time reversal, so $a(r)=0$, as position is even.

As a vector, it is parity odd, so $b(r)=0$.

The final term is the cross product of a vector and an axial vector, so it's parity odd. It is also time odd, since ${\bf S}$ is.

Hence:

$$ {\bf A} = c(r)({\bf  r} \times {\bf S}) $$

describes the structure.

The field cannot be too complicated, as it is a dipole field, so it must have the same symmetries as a dipole. It is:

$$ {\bf A} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{{\bf m} \times {\bf r}}{r^3} $$

with:

$$ {\bf m} = -g\frac{e\hbar}{4m_ec}{\bf \sigma}$$